# Execute ALTER SYSTEM command in oracle scheduler

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, jobs

I would like to set a job in the scheduler which will do a change of the resource manager plan.

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name             => 'scott.dayplan',
       job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
       job_action           => 'BEGIN ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN = 'dayplan'; END;'
       start_date           => '17-MAY-10 01.00.00 AM Europe/Warsaw',
       repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=8;',
       end_date             => '99-SEP-04 01.00.00 AM Europe/Warsaw',
       comments             => 'Resource manager daytime plan');
    END;
    /
```

But the `job_action` is given wrong. Any ideas how to execute alter system command in create job function?

Comment: And this is why we have scheduler windows. You do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create procedure to run your SQL statements then call that procedure in `job_action`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc
as
begin
execute immediate 'ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN=DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN';
end;
/  

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC dbms_scheduler.drop_job('job1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
   job_name          =>  'job1',
   job_type          =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action        =>  'begin my_proc(); end;',
   start_date        =>  SYSDATE,
   repeat_interval   =>  'FREQ = DAILY; INTERVAL = 1');
END;
/    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC dbms_scheduler.run_job('job1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> select log_date, status from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name='JOB1';

LOG_DATE                                STATUS
-------------------------------------   --------------
10-MAY-17 06.36.43.906003 AM -04:00     SUCCEEDED
```

Starting from Oracle 12c, we have `SQL_SCRIPT` as `job_type` which specifies that the job is a SQL*Plus script.

[DBMS_SCHEDULER: Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm)

Moreover, if you just want to switch resource allocation plan, as Balaz Papp mentioned in the comment, you could use Scheduler Windows.

> You create windows to automatically start jobs or to change resource allocation among jobs during various time periods of the day

[Oracle Scheduler Concepts: Window](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedover.htm#ADMIN-GUID-21008E86-682F-4375-AA0C-D9A315B086E3)

Comment: @BartCh. Sorry that I didn't notice that you are using Oracle 12c. You could use new feature, `SQL_SCRIPT`, see the documentation for details.

Comment: @JSapkota,yes in Oracle 12c there is SQL_SCRIPT feature.

Comment: @JSapkota, There is also no dba_job_run_details table. But in documetation it is said "The job log includes the data dictionary views `*_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG` and `*_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`, where: `* = {DBA|ALL|USER}"`

Comment: @BartCh.: My mistake, a typo, it should be `dba_scheduler_job_run_details`, in fact I typed the statement and copied the output from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable the job. Like that it will run only once
execute dbms_scheduler.enable('JOB1');

Nice code though